# Absolute motion analysis of a mechanism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider the below mechanism. Link AB rotates CCW with a constant angular velocity $w$. I am supposed to express the velocity and acceleraton of block C (which is confined to move vertically) for when $\theta=60^\circ$ in terms of given symbolics. [image]
[image]
I tried to perform an absolute motion analysis on this. Let the angle between link BC and the horizontal be $\phi$ and let the translational coordinate of C be y, starting from its current position. The geometry of the problem lets us write

$L\,\cos\theta+L\,\cos\phi=L$  **(1)**

so

$\cos\theta+\cos\phi=1$

Because $\theta=60^\circ$ for the instant, $\phi=60^\circ$ too.
Time derivative of **(1)** is

$-\large\sin\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}-\sin\phi\frac{d\phi}{dt}=0$ **(2)**

Installing numerical values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ after getting rid of minus signs

$\large\sin60\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\sin60\frac{d\phi}{dt}=0$ which yields

$\large\frac{d\phi}{dt}=-\frac{d\theta}{dt}$=$-w$

$w$ is constant so

$\large\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}$=$\large\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=0$ **(3)**

Differentiating **(2)** with respect to time gives:

$\large(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2\cos\theta+\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\sin\theta+(\frac{d\phi}{dt})^2\cos\phi+\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}\sin\phi=0$

$w$ is constant, so $\large\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=0$. Along with $\theta=60^\circ$, $\phi=60^\circ$ and $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$=$w$ I end up with:

$w^2\cos60\,+\,0\,+w^2\cos60\,+\,0=0$ This is the step I am stuck. $\large\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=0$ means $w=0$ which is not true and defying **(3)** and stating $\large\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}\ne0$ gives

$w^2/2+0*\sin60+w^2/2+0.866\large \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=0$ which results in

$\large\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-1.155w^2$

I am missing something and I cannot find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity $\dot\theta=\omega$ is constant, but $\dot \phi=-\dot\theta=-\omega$ only at the moment of $\theta=\phi=60^\circ$.

Consider $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x$. Both $f(0)=g(0)=0$ at $x=0$, but $f'(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$.

If you write down $\dot\phi$ as a function of $\theta$ (and $\phi$), then by differentiating it, you will see that $\ddot\phi\neq0$.